# ImportError: No module named pynotify. While the module is installed

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, importerror, pynotify

So this error keeps coming back.

Everytime I try to tun the script it returns saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cli.py", line 11, in <module>
    import pynotify
ImportError: No module named pynotify
```

The strange thing is, I just installed this plugin.
I also restarted command prompt already, even the computer.

But nothing, if anyone could help me out here that'd be great!

Comment: How did you install the package? via `pip`?

Comment: correct, I did a pip install

Comment: Try running `import sys; print sys.path` to see where your runtime is searching for installed packages. Make sure that pynotify is in one of those locations.

Comment: it prints a lot of things, but I can not find pynotify along the lines it prints.

Comment: @OlavAlberts Please accept [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34955039/780752) answer

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
pip install py-notify
```

It worked for me.

Comment: `py-notify` is not same as `pynotify`. Please refer https://ole.im/blog/2011/oct/20/python-notify

Answer (score 2):

You are most likely looking for `pyinotify` not `pynotify`. That should fix your ImportError.

Comment: no the script on github definitely says: pynotify, thanks for the reply though!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution for Ubuntu.

First install `python-notify`: `sudo apt-get install python-notify`
After that you may need to add the right paths:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0')
sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/')
```

Finally: `import pynotify`

Answer (score 1):

first check your `pip`version and your `python` running version

> pip --version, python --version

if the `pip` is from python3's packages. and you python environment is running at python2.x. so abandon using your `pip`  to install any `notify` , you just install  `python-notify`

Answer (score 0):

If what you install is py-notify (http://home.gna.org/py-notify/), it should be:

```
import notify
```

Comment: hmm The script says: from datetime import datetime
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import getpass
import sched
import time
import threading
import psutil
import signal
import pynotify
import Queue

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you were using the corresponding pip version for your version of Python. For example, if you have Python2 and Python3 installed, you may have installed `pynotify` for Python2, and attempting to import it from Python3, which will result in the package not being found.

Try running

```
pip --version
```

Assuming `pip install` is how you installed the package as well as

```
python --version
```

to ensure the version numbers are similar.

Comment: pip 1.5.6 from C:\Python27\lib\site-packages (python 2.7) |
Python 2.7.8

Answer (score 0):

Import package 'notify' instead of 'pynotify'

```
import notify
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is because, you had run the Python file (mitmf.py) with python2. But you have installed pyinotify in python3-pip. So it will only run in pip2.To install it follow the link... https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-pip-on-ubuntu-20.04/